# What does a "\" mean in a formula is SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

This is an existing formula in an SSRS expression. What does the \ (backslash) do?

```
=Sum(Fields!Active.Value, "DataSet1")/sum(Sum(Fields!township_area_max.Value,"townshiparea")\count(Fields!township_area_max.Value,"townshiparea"))
```

I understand "/" in an expression (aka formula) but have never seen a \ (backslash) used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash divides the number but only returns an Integer result.

```
11 \ 2 = 5
```

The description is in SSRS's Expression Builder items.
[image]